# How to KEEP empty line after removing duplicates in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to remove duplicates by using Notepad++, but in previous versions there was a default way to do that and leave empty lines. Now it isn't helping, or I am missing something.

The whole idea is the following - when I have 1000 lines with duplicated text/links with code, I will select "Remove Duplicate Lines” option and I if all of my lines was duplicated I will see 500 lines. But I want to see 1000 rows and play with empty lines/rows.

In example I have identical lines of code like this:

```
href a 
href a 
href a 
href b 
href b
```

I want to achieve this:

```
href a 
empty line 
empty line 
empty line 
href b 
empty line
```

And using search and replace isn’t an option because there are 3k+ lines when unique lines are around 1k What I am missing here?

Empty lines are needed for me because I will manipulate with it after pasting to the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in a single pass.
Here is a way to go but it needs the <kbd>replace all</kbd> key to be press as many times as needed.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select "Mark" tab
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)$\R+\K\1`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
\R+         # 1 or more any kind of linebreak
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\1          # backreference to group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]